# How to delete files from multiple paths in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, path

I was following a tutorial on creating a Python script for deleting files that are older than a certain amount of days. I was able to successfully create the script and have it do what I want but now I need it to scan multiple paths not just the one. How would I go about doing that?

This is what I have:

```
import os
import datetime
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST FILES TO DELETE'
logging_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Delete Logs'

# Create log directory, wills skip if exists
if not os.path.isdir(logging_path):
    os.mkdir(logging_path)
else:
    print ("Directory already exists")

today = datetime.datetime.today() # Get current time
os.chdir(path) # Changing path to current path

# Create log file with timestamp
file=open(logging_path+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')+'.txt','a')

for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        # Check last modified time
        t = os.stat(os.path.join(root, name))[8]
        filetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) - today

        # Is file older than 3 days?, If yes, delete.
        if filetime.days <= -3:
            print(os.path.join(root, name), filetime.days)
            file.write(os.path.join(root, name)+' created '+str(-1*filetime.days)+' days ago\n')
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

This is what I tried doing:

```
import os
import datetime
import glob

path = [r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST FILES TO DELETE', r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST FILES TO DELETE3']
logging_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Delete Logs'

# Create log directory, wills skip if exists
if not os.path.isdir(logging_path):
    os.mkdir(logging_path)
else:
    print ("Directory already exists")

today = datetime.datetime.today() # Get current time
os.chdir(path) # Changing path to current path

# Create log file with timestamp
file=open(logging_path+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')+'.txt','a')

for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        # Check last modified time
        t = os.stat(os.path.join(root, name))[8]
        filetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) - today

        # Is file older than 3 days?, If yes, delete.
        if filetime.days <= -3:
            print(os.path.join(root, name), filetime.days)
            file.write(os.path.join(root, name)+' created '+str(-1*filetime.days)+' days ago\n')
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

After trying this though I get an error about chdir on line 15. I'm clearly missing something but I don't know enough about Python or programming to figure that out yet.

Comment: You changed the meaning of variable `path`. I think you should rename it as `paths`, and then check where you have `path` (which probably expect a single path, not a list). Probably there you should insert a `for path in paths:`. When you change the semantic, change variable names, so it is easier to find where you may have problems.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Giacomo Catenazzi alredy explained, you changed the data type of path (from a string to a list, wich is incompatible whith chdir). So you need to go through each member of your list like this:

```
for p in path:
    os.chdir(p)
    # the rest of your code
```

Note that you need to update every path to p.

Answer (score 0):

Your `path` variable is an array of paths and accordingly rename it to `paths`, you need to either index the array in your `os.chdir` and your `os.walk` or change the path variable to be a string of one specific path.